# Can anyone confirm Titanfall language change?

Tags: titanfall

Now can anyone confirm that Battlefield 4 solution to cahnge the language by copying native GDFBinary_en_US(64).dll to installation (from beta etc) and changing registry keys asociated with origin from ru_RU to en_US? Until the game is not released ofitialy i can't confirm but internet sources confirm that the game perloader does include all the audio files for 11 languages and that is what packed into the 35gb of audio data. So i'm holding my fingers crossed and hoping that dll from beta will work ok. Hoping someone with english version of Titanfall can share RTM version of the DLL.

Comment: Sharing any of these files is violating copyright laws (and the rules for this site).

Also the GDF binary won't help you, since that's only a small helper DLL used for Windows' Games library (game definition file).

Comment: Thank you for reminding the rules. Meaning the game shud (theoricaly) be ok with beta dll, changed registry keys and there is no need of audio that is present already.

Comment: It probably won't be that easy, because I assume the game simply won't include all the localization data. How big has your installation been and how big is your installation folder?

Comment: You can check the "vpk" sub folder. There should be files starting with "englishclient", "frenchclient", "germanclient", etc. If there aren't you're out of luck.

Comment: All the downloaded data is 49,99Gb..